# Cron Job: Best Practices

Tags: bash, shell-script, centos, rhel, cron

I have written a bash script which will be setup as a `cron` job in the future.

During the script development I have added `echo` lines to help me follow and debug my code, like the code snippet below:

```
#!/bin/bash

# Check to see if a LOG file exists
if [ -f $LOGDIR/$LOG_FILE ]; then
  echo "LOG file exists"
  # Clear the contents of the LOG file if already present
  echo -n "" > $LOGDIR/$LOG_FILE
elif [ ! -f $LOGDIR/$LOG_FILE ]; then
  echo "LOG file does not exist. Creating now..."
  touch $LOGDIR/$LOG_FILE
  if [ $? -eq 0 ]; then
    echo "LOG file created successfully"
    elif [ ! $? -eq 0 ]; then
    echo "Unable to create file. Logging disabled"
  fi
fi
```

I just wanted to know if I should comment out the `echo` lines once I setup a `cron job` since the user will not see them. Additionally I am not sure if there is a performance implication when a `cron job` is running that has `echo` lines.

I would like to know some good practices when implementing `cron jobs`, thank you.

Comment: Do you think what you want to do is enough to warrant spending this much effort on setting up logging?  I think you're overthinking it and would be better served by just writing whatever output to the output file and exiting with a non-zero exit status if that fails.  The cron daemon will send the owner of the cron job a message containing the standard error output containing the error.

Comment: Hello, I just included a snippet of my code as an example, to support my question.

Comment: Since you're ending up with a zero-length file whether or not one exists to begin with, what is the advantage to testing for its existence? That is to say, why not `echo -n "" > $LOGDIR/$LOG_FILE` regardless and be done with it?

Comment: The example shown is just a snippet of my full bash script, just to inform users of the type of `echo` outputs I am using. What you see is not the full function of my bash script.

Comment: Most of your tests of exit status are wrong. The value of `$?` is not related to the last external command you ran: almost all shell command (including `test` `[` `[[` and `echo` themselves) reset `$?` too. If you want the exit status of your tests to be stable, you must save them `rc1="${?}"` etc *immediately* after the command itself, and then test that variable. Try `false; echo $?; echo $?` as an example.

Comment: @Paul_Pedant Thank you for your advise. In my past search when learning about bash scripting, the `$?` method always came up in examples and guides.

Answer (score 1):

Lots of ways to slice-n-dice this based on your preferences ...

My approach:

- store scripts in a local 'bin' directory
- the scripts write to their own `<script_name>.log` file in a local 'logs' directory
- crontab entries append all output to a `<script_name>.cronlog` file in the local 'logs' directory
- I also tend to add a `date` call to all of my crontab entries so that I can tell where each new invocation starts in the `*.cronlog` file

My `crontab` then looks like:

```
bindir=/path/to/bin
logdir=/path/to/logs

00,15,30,45 * * * * { date; ${bindir}/script_1; } >> ${logdir}/script_1.cronlog 2>&1
00          * * * * { date; ${bindir}/script_2; } >> ${logdir}/script_2.cronlog 2>&1
```

The script (eg, `script_1`) then has 2 ways to generate output:

- explicitly direct `echo` output to `script_1.log` (or `$LOGDIR/$LOG_FILE` in your script)
- implicitly direct `echo` output to stdout (ie, no redirection of the `echo` output) in which case the `echo` output will be captured in the `script_1.cronlog` file

My personal preference is to write scripts that explicitly direct *all* output to a `<script_name>.log` file and leave the `<script_name>.cronlog` to capture any (`cron`) runtime errors/messages.

Answer (score 1):

Standard coding practice should apply here, regardless of it being run from `cron` or not. For example,

- Double quote your variables when you use them, so that the shell doesn't have any opportunity to word split or glob
- Aim to use lowercase variable names rather than fully uppercase, so that they don't clash with typical uppercase environment variables
- Write debug statements to *stderr*, leaving the normal program flow free to use *stdout*

Here's how you might write that snippet

```
#!/bin/bash
logDir=...
logFile=...
DBG=false    # or "true"

# Check to see if a LOG file exists
if [ -f "$logDir/$logFile" ]
then
    $DBG && echo "Log file exists: $logDir/$logFile" >&2
    > "$logDir/$logFile"
else
    echo "Log file does not exist. Creating: $logDir/$logFile" >&2
    if touch "$logDir/$logFile"
    then
        echo "Log file created successfully" >&2
    else
        echo "Unable to create file. Logging disabled" >&2
    fi
fi
```

Although personally I'd wrap that up in a logging function something like this untested version:

```
#!/bin/bash

log() {
    local dt=$(date +'%Y%m%d_%H%M%S') toTerm=false msg=

    # "+" prefix mandates writing to stderr
    [ "$1" = + ] && toTerm=true && shift

    msg=$(
        if [ $# -gt 0 ] then
            printf '%s: %s\n' "$dt" "$*"
        else
            sed "s/^/$dt: /"
        fi
    )

    # write to stderr if mandated or enabled
    if ${logTerm:-false} || $toTerm; then printf '%s' "$msg" >&2; fi

    # write to logfile if enabled and it exists
    [ -n "$logPath" ] && [ -f "$logPath" ] && { printf '%s' "$msg" >>"$logPath"; } 2>/dev/null
}

logPath=/path/to/logfile        # Enable all logging to file
logTerm=false                   # Do not copy logging to terminal (stderr)

log + 'Logging is enabled'      # Write a message to logfile and terminal
log 'Written to the logfile'    # Write a message just to the logfile
who | log                       # Write a block of text to the terminal

logPath=/path/to/logfile        # Enable all logging to file
logTerm=true                    # Copy all logging to terminal (stderr)

log + 'Logging is enabled'      # Write a message to logfile and terminal
log 'Written to the logfile'    # Write a message to both the logfile and terminal
who | log                       # Write a block of text to both the logfile and terminal
```

Comment: I'd use `logger`. Read `man logger`.

Comment: @waltinator often I do, but for whatever reason I didn't think of it when answering this question. You'd get a +1 for me for sure if that were an answer

Answer (score 1):

My principles for cron jobs:

1. Output progress messages to stdout
2. Progress messages say what action the script is *about to* do, not what the script just did
3. Write the crontab entry to redirect stdout and stderr to /dev/null (e.g. `* * * * * /path/to/my/script >/dev/null 2>&1`)

A lot of people (especially ruby/python/java programmers) prefer the code to be silent.  With cron jobs this is a mistake (IMO).  The first troubleshooting step anyone will do is invoke the script/program by hand to see error messages.  They will see the progress messages in their terminal and see exactly what the script/program was trying to do when it failed.  When the script/program is silent, this useful troubleshooting info is lost.  Since the crontab entry discards the output (due to the redirects to /dev/null), the script/program output will not cause cron to send status e-mails to anyone.

For the script/program writer who has a terrible, crushing phobia against outputting status messages by default, an alternative can be to implement a `-v` / `--verbose` option to turn them on.  However, for simple scripts this is usually much more work than to always output the status messages and hide them from crond with redirections in the crontab entry.

**Extra Emphasis here:**

Lots of people output progress messages after each major action the script/program takes.  This is bad.  Output progress messages **before** their actions.  A great many problems appear when a command/function-call seems to hang for a long time before erroring out.  When the progress messages are written after the action, the script will hang and the user watching the output will not have a message indicating what action/command is hanging.  The last message visible is for the wrong thing (a successful action).  When the message is written before the action, it's clear what part of the script/program is having the trouble.

The above are my opinion about cron job best practices, formed as a Unix and Linux sysadmin over the past 33 years.

Answer (score -1):

i recently just briefly cried about cron on debian. switched over to a systemd service. cron is a pain in the ass =) systemd service is heaven

**example:**

*cat MYSERVICE.service*

```
[Unit]
Description=MYSERVICE-SCRIPT.bash
After=default.target

[Service]
ExecStart=/<ABS-PATH-TO-SCRIPT>/MYSERVICE-SCRIPT.bash

[Install]
WantedBy=default.target
```

then move it to `/etc/systemd/system/MYSERVICE.service`

after that you have control via `systemctl enable/disable/start/stop/status MYSERVICE`

Comment: Your systemd service requires a manual restart every time you need the script to run. The requirement to use cron could likely be that the script needs to run on a regular, periodic schedule. Yes, this can be done with systemd timers but your service file will need changing to take advantage of this.